# Very low power: Most power-efficient way of storing charge for hours

Tags: batteries, capacitor, low-power, charge

I'm researching the feasibility of doing an art project that involves soaking up ambient RF power in a city (energy harvesting) and then playing a 1 second sound clip through a speaker as soon as there is enough stored energy to do so. There will be no other source of energy -- not solar, not anything, just ambient RF harvesting.

It looks like RF harvesting might give me about 10 microwatts.  And my 1 second sound clip, played at human speaking volume with an efficient amplifier should need about 10 microwatt-hours. So I would need to charge some kind of battery or capacitor for say 1-5 hours at 10 microwatts, and then discharge it in 1 second and repeat.

Given that, what might be some options for storage devices/circuits? Which are the most efficient and most inefficient setups for the parameters stated? In other words, is there any charge storage tech that could achieve the above behavior?

Answer (score 2):

A capacitor may be the least lossy store BUT the capacitor size needed may surprise you.

Energy in a capacitor = \$ \frac{C V^2}{2} \$
Energy when a capacitor is discharged from \$V_1\$ to \$V_2\$ =
\$E = \frac{C(V_1^2 - V_2^2)}{2} \$
Rearranging \$ C = \frac{2E}{V_1^2 - V_2^2} \$
Plug in some made up figures to get a feel for magnitudes.:
Vmax = 5 V, Vmin = 3 V.
E = 10 µWh = 36000 µW seconds = 0.036 watt seconds = 0.036 joule.

\$ C = \frac{2E}{V_1^2 - V_2^2} = 2 \cdot 3.6 \cdot \frac{10^{-2}}{5^2 - 3^2} = 7.2 \cdot \frac{10^{-4}}{16} = 4500 \$ µF.
Ceramic and most plastic capacitors would be liable to be low enough loss. 
Any electrolytic capacitor is liable to be excessively lossy.
 4500 uF is an immensely large value for a non electrolytic capacitor.

Storage at higher voltage will decrease required capacitance by the square of the voltage. eg at 50 V you need \$ \approx \$ 47 µF or less

However, I'd at least consider battery storage. It's possible that a small Lithium ion battery may do the job. If you want say 36 mJ in 1 second that's \$ 0.036 \cdot 3600 \$ W  \$\approx 130 \$ W !!!. That's FAR more than you need for the stated application.

E&OE - going to sleep at keyboard (long day on 3 hours sleep) - I'll post this now and check figures later and look at battery implications.

More anon ...

Answer (score 1):

The only possible (and often used in practice) is a capacitor. You will need some low leakage capacitor with big enough capacitance.

You have to estimate what capacitance will be enough and if it is up to several tens of microfarads, you can use some SMD ceramic capacitors. They have very little leakage. For higher capacitances tantalum capacitors are suitable.

Also, some micropower, switching converter should be designed in order to fit the voltage to a reasonable values. I saw somewhere resonance LC converters that can work from 50mV power supply. (You will need some Ge BJTs for this)

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like RF harvesting might give me about 10 microwatts

10 microwatts of received power via an efficient antenna into a 50 ohm load means the voltage is: -

\$V = \sqrt{10\times 10^{-6}\times 50}\$ = 22mV RMS. This may have a peak voltage of 32mV.

I've not come across an energy harvesting device that can self-start at less than 200mV - that's nearly ten times more than what you are considering. Maybe you know of a device that will do this?

Comment: This is what transformers are for. Even a basic crystal radio works on this principle. If a crystal radio only created 22 mV RF, then no signal would ever make it thru the diode. A RF coil with properly tuned secondary should be able to put out quite a bit more than 22 mV, at a higher impedance than the antenna of course.

Comment: @OlinLathrop in a semi-close-to-ideal situation I'd agree with you but the OP is suggesting "soaking up ambient RF power" and this means a broad swathe of tuning across a wide bandwidth and not focussing on one particular area where there may (or may not be) some RF energy worth collecting. This rules out the tuning the secondary. I can't rule out that the OP can use directional antennas to pin-point a potential RF energy source but that kind-of defeats the objective in my book.

Comment: First, I would identify the strongest AM station in the area and tune for that.  Second, even if you don't tune, you can still use a receiving coil that works like a auto-transformer, just like crystal radios do.

Comment: @OlinLathrop A single AM station has a very good chance of working - if you are fairly close (maybe 10km max at 1MHz). It must kick-out ~ 1kilowatt and at 10km the free space link loss is 32.45dB + 20log(F)dB + 20log(D)dB where F is MHz and D is km - that's 52.45dB loss from a signal of +60dBm, leaving +7dBm for reception. Given all sorts of non-free-space issues you'll probably get 20dB lower at -13dBm. That's about 50\$\mu W\$ and of course tunable because it's 1 frequency (+ sidebands). You'll probably get a 10:1 tuning peak taking the volts from 50mV to 500mV rms. Do-able!